# Razor Page Create Input Type Date Turns Into Type Text

Tags: html, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, .net-5

I have a model which is of DateTime type and want to create textbox for it. The default generated control's type is `datetime-local`. I want to change it to `date` only since I don't need the time. However, for some reason the type always turned to `text` type after loading is finished.

Here is my code

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label asp-for="Order.TanggalOrder" class="control-label">Tanggal Order</label>
  <input asp-for="Order.TanggalOrder" type="date" class="" />
  <input asp-for="Order.TanggalOrder" type="time" class="form-control" />
  <span asp-validation-for="Order.TanggalOrder" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

[image: input date turns into input text]

As you can see, the browser rendered the `date` input correctly for a brief moment, then turned into `text`. The datepicker is still there, but the input validation (`dd/mm/yyyy` text and calendar icon ) is no longer there.

This happens only with `date` type, as I tried it with `time` or `datetime` and they're still rendered properly.

Any clue on what I have to do?
I'm using the .net 5 mvc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use separate date and time controls. In order for the input tag helper to present the correct controls, more configuration is needed:

Model:

```
[BindProperty, DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
```

View:

```
DateTime:
<input class="form-control" asp-for="Date" />
```

Result:
[image]

[image]